# Why don't adjectives agree with nouns in English?

Tags: adjectives, history, agreement

I had never actually thought about this before now, probably because I'm a native speaker of English. But once I gave it some thought, I was actually a little surprised that adjectives in English do not have agreements (as far as I know), especially given the numerous intricacies of the English language and its largely French/Latin influences.

Did English have adjective agreements at some point? Are there no adjective agreements because there is no grammatical gender?

Comment: What nature of agreement are you referring to?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of where they don’t agree, but could under some different system?

Comment: @fixer1234 Noun agreement. I probably should have been clearer. Similar to French how you'll have colours "agree" with a feminine noun, e.g. "la maison blanche".

Comment: @Jim It's not so much that they don't agree semantically, it's that they don't agree grammatically when compared to other European languages like French. I'm by no means criticising English - I love the language! - but I'm just curious as to why, being a European language, it does not have adjective-noun agreements.

Comment: I think you just need to switch your viewpoint and consider that they always make agreement but since there is no difference in noun forms there is also no difference in the adjective forms.

Comment: @fixer1234 I'm average at best at French, so I understand. If I put it another way, the adjective "blanc" ("white") would **not** agree with the noun if it kept its masculine form: "la maison blanc" - wrong.

Comment: Could the argument be made that they **do** "agree" since there is nothing to disagree about in English (no gender-based forms in that sense)?

Comment: @fixer1234 Potentially. But we do have plurals!

Comment: English is Germanic—there is no “largely French/Latin origin”. There are many _loan words_ from French and Latin, but the language itself is Germanic. Of course, nearly all other Germanic languages have both genders and noun–adjective agreement as well, so it's not the origin of the language that explains it. English used to have extensive agreement as well, but has lost it because unstressed final syllables have been lost—that simple.

Comment: @fixer1234 in English, the adjective does not have to agree with noun gender e.g. "a difficult problem". In Italian, "problem" is masculine and is written *problema*, the indefinite article agrees with the gender: ***un*** *problema difficil**e***, but when Italians pluralize the noun, they also have to pluralize the adjective: two difficult problems = *due problem**i*** *difficil**i***

Comment: @Mari-LouA, is there a simple, rule-based logic for assigning gender to words, or do language learners basically just need to memorize the gender of every word?

Comment: @fixer1234 there's no memorization involved, it comes naturally to native speakers. Although grammatical errors and slip ups can occur  that's the same for any speaker, regardless of the  language they speak. I chose the noun *problema* for two reasons; it's easy for English speakers to recognise, and because those pesky Italians had to write it with the suffix -a which is normally feminine, compare *bambin**o*** (male baby) and *bambin**a*** (female baby). There are loads of similar irregularities in the Italian language.

Comment: @fixer1234 - the gender agreement is probably the main mistake that non-native speakers make even after years they have been  living in countries like France of Italy for instance.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - spell-checkers traps... no, a native Italian would never say "la problema" or "il mano" even without any education...these are typical NNSs mistakes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Just in case you don’t already know this (you probably do, but still): the reason _problema_ is masculine is that it comes from an Ancient Greek class of neuter nouns that end in _-ma_ (in Greek, their plural ends in _-mata_, like _stigma/stigmata_, but this is of course lost in most cases in the modern languages). Neuter words nearly always became masculine when the neuter gender was lost in the Romance languages. If you have a noun ending in _-ma_ in Italian/Spanish/Portuguese (or _-me_ in French), there’s a very good chance it’s masculine.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet No, I did not know why, it's good know whom I can blame now :) You never fail to amaze me with your polyglotism.

Comment: @fixer1234 There are many rules that will help you guess the gender of a noun. As Mari-Lou says, the general rule is that words in _-o_ are masculine and those in _-a_ are feminine. Words in _-e_ can be either (or sometimes both), but most are masculine. Then there are particular suffixes that always form words of a specific gender: _-(z)ione_ (= English _-(t)ion_) always forms feminines, for example. And then there are all the exceptions (like feminine _mano_ or masculine _poeta_). So it’s both: general rules that help, but you still need to know it for each word.

Comment: According to [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blonde), there is at least one arguable exception.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It's a curious exception though: the form of the adjective depends on the person you're talking about, not necessarily the noun being modified: *a boy with blond hair, a girl with blonde hair*.

Comment: @Jacinto Hence 'arguable'. I'm not even going to go into what the consensus is when speaking about poodles of said colour.

Comment: @fixer1234 there's something to be said about speaking two or more languages and/or learning a new language, I've read it wards off alzheimer's and dementia, but I don't remember where I got it from, so maybe it's just a myth. Good exercise for the brain, all the same.

Comment: English is a kind of creole language, a mixture of Germanic languages and French. Creoles tend to be grammatically more simple than their parent languages.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, you don't remember where you got it from?  Sounds like languages may not be providing the mythical benefit.  :-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Fair enough. I shall do that.

Answer (score 21):

According to the following [source](http://blog.dictionary.com/oldenglishgender/), it is not clear why gender agreement (which existed in OE) disappeared. It was probably due to simplify communication between Old English and Old Norse:

> - If you speak another language like Spanish or German, you are familiar with grammatical gender. In Romance languages (and many others), nouns have a gender. In French, a chair is la chaise, a feminine noun, and a hat is le chapeau, a masculine noun. But did you know that English used to have gendered nouns too?
> - ***Until the 1200s, English had grammatical gender. Instead of using the articles “the” or “a”, Old English had a masculine article “se” and a feminine article “seo”***. The sun, for instance, was feminine, so it would be written “sēo sunne”. If you referred to the sun, you would even say “she”.
> - ***However, in northern England in the 1100s, grammatical gender disappeared. Historical linguists aren’t entirely sure why this happened, but Professor [Anne Curzan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_Curzan) suggests that genders were lost because of the language mixing that went on in Northern England during that time***.
> - Between the 700s and the 1000s, there were Vikings invading northern England where peasants lived. The two groups spoke different languages: Old English and Old Norse. However, it is quite likely that many people were bilingual and fluent in both languages. ***Both Old English and Old Norse had gender, but sometimes their genders contradicted each other. In order to simplify communication, gendered nouns simply disappeared***.

(blog.dictionary.com)

According to the following extract from [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-nouns-in-English-have-gender), the introduction, and usage of the gender-neutral article "þe (the)" is probably responsible for the decline in usage of gender agreement in the English language. ***I personally think this is an interesting assumption*** so I add it as additional information on this topic:

> - Unlike most other Indo-European languages which have gender, English introduced an article — þe (the) — that was gender neutral. Since most of England in the 13th-17th centuries was uneducated, it was a great time for language change. The article þe was much easier to learn than arbitrary gendered articles, so it started to be used by everyone.
> - And around the 14th century, Colloquial English started to drop the declensions present in proper Old English, and with it, grammatical gender disappeared.

Comment: +1 Nice information about the genders. I have always wondered how English would handle grammatical gender.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - it is clearly a deduction, but a reasonable one (IMO) there is no clear answer to this question, but  the introduction of  the gender-neutral article for nouns may easily have contributed to the move towards a grammatical genderless agreement.

Comment: Odd that disappearing gender disappearing in 12th century England is traced to gender disagreements between Old English and Norse rather than Ang and Norman French. Anyone have a brief outline of why Curzan would argue that?

Comment: @lly Probably because it happened first in the _north_ of England where the Scandinavian presence was quite strong and the Norman presence much less so, combined with the fact that Norman French was a very different language, while Old Norse was a closely related one that would have been _almost_ mutually intelligible. It’s not particularly difficult to remember that _hūs_ in your own language is neuter, while _meson_ in NF is feminine; much harder to keep track of almost identical words that have different genders. But even more so, what Curzon argues is based not so much on the gender →

Comment: I might be thick here, but how does this relate to *one **big** house* vs *two **big** houses*. Other Germanic languages have adjective agreement when pluralized.

Comment: → itself, but of the inflectional paradigms that went along with each. Old English and Old Norse were very closely related, but the way they inflected nouns differed a lot. So if you were bilingual(ish), as much of Northern England probably was, for the word ‘day’ you’d have to keep track of two paradigms: **OE** sg. NA _dæġ_, G _dæġes_, D _dæġe_; pl. NA _dagas_, G _daga_, D _dagum_ — vs. **ON**, sg. N _dagr_, A _dag_, G _dags_, D _degi_; pl. N _dagar_, AG _daga_, D _dǫgum_. See how that can be tricky? And it was like that for virtually _all_ words.

Comment: Do note that “a chair” is “*une chaise*” and a “a hat” is “*un chapeau*”. French has grammatical gender, but it also has indefinite articles.

Answer (score 1):

During the period when England was under the rule of the Normans, French was the official language. Old English, or Anglo-Saxon, was still spoken by the non-ruling class, but it underwent many changes such as the accent on words being moved to the front. Unaccented syllables dropped off, including most of the inflections. New words (and thousands of French words entered the language during this time) when brought into the language were never given the inflections to begin with. When English finally became the official language again (not until the 1500s), it was vastly different (think Chaucer versus Shakespeare).